# reactjs how background image resize according window size

Tags: css, reactjs

I am currently on a reactJs project. How do i set the background image that can resize according window size especially When toggle device toolbar.

```
.container{
    background: url('../image/2.png'); 
}
```

By using this the background image is fix, what should i do to make it flexible?

Comment: Try "background-size" (background-size: cover;) or (background-size: contain;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use background-size: contain and even set the background position

Comment: When i set my background-size: contain, how should i set my height to fit the background size? when i try to set height to fit it not work.

Comment: set the height of .container 100%, it will take the 100% of t he parent div, and when you'll resize the height will also be resized